# mpv: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, codec, mpv

System:
Linux 6.1.21-1-MANJARO

After updating/upgrading my system, mpv no longer works. It seems ffmpeg is using libavcodec 60 and mpv is using 59. Though I'm not 100% sure this is the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After updating/upgrading my system, mpv no longer works. It seems ffmpeg is using libavcodec 60 and mpv is using 59.

Use `pacman -Qo` on both programs (with `which mpv` to find out its path) to verify whether both packages were installed from the official repositories.

- If they were – it's the Manjaro ffmpeg/mpv packagers' responsibility to solve this problem; they should have published a rebuilt mpv package for libavcodec 60 at the exact same time as they published the new ffmpeg. (Or, at least, they should have rebuilt it to depend on "ffmpeg5" if the new version was incompatible.)

  (It's also technically possible for your package mirror to end up grabbing a package database that was only partially updated, such that it had the new ffmpeg but the old mpv, but that should be rare – and the problem should go away after the mirror's next refresh, in an hour at most.)

  Either way, repeat a system upgrade, and make sure your package versions match those listed on the distribution's website.
- On the other hand, if mpv has been installed from a locally-built package (AUR or similar), then *you* must rebuild it to use the new libraries.

Also: It might be useful to run `lddtree` on the mpv executable and verify whether the bad library dependency comes directly from mpv itself or whether it comes as a transitive dependency from another library. Sometimes it is a library "in the middle" that needs to be updated or rebuilt.

Comment: I think that revealed the issue thanks mate! mpv executable is present in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` doing `ldd mpv | grep codec` in both directories reveals that the issue is in `/usr/local/bin` uses `libavcodec.so.59` and `/usr/bin uses libavcodec.so.60`. I deleted that executable now when I run mpv it says `usr/local/bin/pmv: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Restart your shell or do `hash -r` to have it forget the cached path.

Comment: Great its working now! The main issue has been solved.  I am getting some warnings but they don't seem to be causing any issue: `[ffmpeg] NULL: non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[ffmpeg/video] h264: non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period`